# What's wrong with my logic?

Tags: haskell, persistent, yesod

```
>main :: IO ()
 main = withPostgresqlConn "host=localhost user=Rocko port=5432 dbname=Rocko" $           runSqlConn $ do
   runMigration migrateAll
   let compDay = C.fromGregorian 2011 11 21
   match <- selectList
              [TestStartDate ==. compDay,
               TestEstimatedEnd ==. compDay,
               TestStatus /<-. [Passed,Failed]] []
   scheduled <- selectList [TestStatus ==. Scheduled] []
--   liftIO $ print scheduled
   liftIO $ print match
   if (L.null match == True) then (liftIO $ print "date available!!!! ") else (liftIO $       print "date not available")
   return ()
```

I'm trying to determine if a particular Day meets this criteria: is not equal to a TestStartDate, is not equal to a TestEstimatedEnd, and neither Passed not Failed is a member of TestStatus.

However, I want to demonstrate that with the date I picked (which should have a match on an TestEstimatedEnd) fails to do the right thing. It should say , :date not available. So what is wrong with my logic?

```
> id |         firmware          |  version   | startDate  | estimatedEnd |  status

>----+---------------------------+------------+------------+--------------+-----------
  >1 | BCC Admin                 | 0.0.00.001 | 2011-11-19 | 2011-11-21   | Scheduled

>ghcifoo> main
 "date available!!!! "
```

Comment: To clarify: should it be saying the date is available when there are no matching dates?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do.

Comment: Are the conditions in selectList conjunctive (&&) or disjunctive (||)?

Comment: the conditions in selectList are conjunctive.

Comment: with Persistent, `,` means `&&`

Comment: So then you're checking for something with the same start and (estimated) end date, but the jobs usually take several days, so no match.

Comment: I'm checking against these dates. compDay represents user input. I'm checking against dates already in the database. I want to make sure compDay is neither some other job's start nor end date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a difficult problem to replicate so what I'm writing is a pretty wild guess, but here goes:

Lets work backwards from the final result

```
if (L.null match == True) then (liftIO $ print "date available!!!! ") else (liftIO $       print "date not available")
```

This line clearly evaluated the `then` condition. Ergo `(L.null match == True)` was `True`.  My first question is why the `== True` clause?  `L.null match` should work just as well by itself.

Now we know that `L.null match` must have been `True`, but the line above would seem to indicate that `match` contains one record. So at this point I would suspect that `L.null` is perhaps not the function you think it is or match doesn't contain what the output is leading us to believe it does.  My next debugging suggestion would be to test `match` against some other properties (is there a length function maybe?) and see if the problem is with `L.null` or `match`.  Another thought is to move the print statement after the `if`.  That should not change anything (certainly not in Haskell!), but the response from a database query is occasionally *weird*. (e.g. not a list but a *stream* of results that gets consumed as they are used.)

Good Luck!

Comment: Hey thanks for the troubleshooting tips. I was at a loss on how to get to the bottom of this.